# Does PyODE support composite objects?

Tags: python, ode-library, pyode

I'm trying to create a composite object with PyODE, but I can't find any documentation regarding this.

Here is some info I found:

- this is for ODE, the engine that PyODE is a wrapper for, and seems to be the most recent source of information:
  http://opende.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Manual_%28Collision_Detection%29#Composite_objects

Note that it states:

> The geom transform classes are
>   deprecated. Use geom offsets instead.

for PyODE I could only find information regarding geom transform classes:

- http://pyode.sourceforge.net/api-1.2.0/public/ode.GeomTransform-class.html

with no info on how to use them, except for this example for ODE:

- http://opende.sourceforge.net/mediawiki-1.6.10/index.php/HOWTO_composite_objects

and absolutely no info regarding geom offsets for PyODE.
so...

1. Does anyone know if geom offsets are implemented in PyODE? (how can I find out?)
2. If geom offsets do not exist, is there an example somewhere on how to use the old geom transform classes in PyODE?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late Answer, but I thought id post it for others.

You need to call setOffsetPosition() on the other geoms after the have been attached to the same body